# Convert "array of ansichar" to string maintaining Chr(0)

Tags: string, delphi, type-conversion

I have a text inside a variable of datatype `ARRAY[0..60] of Ansichar` which contains "Zero Ascii codes"/`Chr(0)`.
The text looks like this: `'Robot'#0#0'PosX=25'#0`
I want to copy this text inside a string variable *maintaining every single char*.

The following code can be compiled but does not work like expected.

```
var
  MyText: array[0..60] of Ansichar;
  MyString: string;
begin
  ...
  MyString := MyText;
  ...
```

After execution the variable MyString = `'Robot'`. The rest of the string is cut away.

When I try to call a string routine (`MyString := Pos(MyText, 0, 20);`) it does the same by truncating the string at the first occurence of a Chr(0) char.

**How can I convert the text to a string while keeping all chars?**

Comment: If this is Delphi 2009 or later, the conversion from `array[] of AnsiChar` to `string` also involves a change of character encoding (every other byte in the string will be 0).

Comment: I dislike what you're doing here. You take an array, 0..60 initialize the first 14 elements but not the other 47 and expect those 14 elements to make up your string. Those other elements in the array can have any value so this can potentially produce a lot of garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also another solution:

```
  MyString := TEncoding.ANSI.GetString(BytesOf(@MyText[0], Sizeof(MyText)));
```

Even if the loop with intrinsic conversion from AnsiChar to Char is favored, it would give a better performance to allocate the string in advance:

```
  SetLength(MyString, 61);
  for z := 0 to 60 do begin
    MyString[z+1] := MyText[z];
  end;
```

Comment: I suppose this is the modern counterpart to using [`SetString( MyString, @MyText[0], Length( MyText ) )`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SetString) until 2009.

Comment: @AmigoJack The advantage of the TEncoding approach is the ability to use a dedicated codepage when converting AnsiChar, which depends on the current Windows user setting.

Comment: @AmigoJack The `SetString()` approach would still work even in post 2009 versions. Simply `SetString()` the array to an `AnsiString`, then `SetCodePage()` the `AnsiString`, then assign the `AnsiString` to a `(Unicode)String`

Comment: @UweRaabe the RTL's conversions from ANSI to Unicode can be changed at runtime via the `System.DefaultSystemCodePage` variable

Answer (score 0):

This loop helped me to solve the problem.

```
var
  MyText: array[0..60] of Ansichar;
  MyString: string;
  z: integer;
begin
  ...
  MyString := '';
  for z := 0 to 60 do begin
    MyString := MyString + MyText[z];
  end;
  ...
```

Comment: Does it even has to be `String` instead of using `AnsiString` right away?

Comment: Loop should be ``for z := Low(MyText) to High(MyText) do``